# DOMPDF suddenly can't convert HTML to PDF

Tags: dompdf, html-to-pdf

Don't know what happened and I didn't change any code recently, DOMPDF suddenly stops converting my HTML to PDF. When I tried to debug, it is stopping in "$root->reflow();" in the render function. Couldn't able to find the exact problem in that step. I have been sending the same or less content in HTML that I used to send before. Before no problem used to show, now it is redirecting to 404.
Also, I was thinking there might be any problem with the composer or any other classes.

Please help me with this!!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I don't know what to do at this point, I'm asking you guy's to give an idea to debug the problem. When I tried to put reflow() in comments, PDF is generating but without content. Kinda confused that why suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: If some redirect to 404 happens, why not check **where** this happens?

Comment: Hard to deduce the issue without seeing any actual error messages (from the PHP error log, for example). Also, have you made any changes to you system (PHP or Dompdf upgrade)?